# Java Azure service bus throwing error at run time

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/azure/messaging/servicebus/ServiceBusClientBuilder

Tried with dependency version : 7.0.2.

Also tried with latest version of azure service bus dependency causing runtime error.

Tried with all azure service bus dependency still issue persist.

Comment: Also tried with azure bom as mentioned in the link https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/boms/azure-sdk-bom/README.md    .Previously 7.0.2 version was working fine today only faced this issue.

Comment: [ClassNotFoundException: com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusClientBuilder$ServiceBusSenderClientBuilde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72633891/classnotfoundexception-com-azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusclientbuilders#comment128313672_72633891)